How to make view reflect binding object's properties changing internally in SwiftUI?
In this code below, I want the TextField value to be cleared when the button is selected and the object's clear method is called (in reality, my class has many properties so I feel like clearing them all calls for a "clear" function).

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var object = Object()
    
    var body: some View {
        NewView(object: $object)
    }
}

struct NewView: View {
    @Binding var object: Object
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter some text", text: $object.text)
            .border(Color.black, width: 1)
        
        Button("Clear", action: {
            object.text = ""
            object.clear()
        })
    }
    
}

class Object {
    var text = ""
    
    func clear(){
        self.text = ""
    }
}


I've seen other questions about how

"@State must be defined within the view hierarchy"

But I think that's already the case here


"Using onChange or onReceive"

I don't think that would help me either, or else I'm not sure how to use it correctly to update the view elements



I'm so new to SwiftUI, I really don't know what I don't know - should I be using something like Publishers, or ObservedObjects, or would an Environment object work?

@State is just for values or structs not classes

The issue is that you're not linking text property with the others. So, when the text changes, it cannot notify the listener(s), which is TextField:
@Observable //<- add here
class Object {
    ...
}

Or fallback to the previous version:
class Object: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""
    ...
}


Simple @State var ... work with type object (eg struct Object),
not suited for classes,
unless you use the @Observable class Object....
Note, the way TextField work, you need to press the return button to
submit before the clear button can take effet.
struct Object {
    var text = ""
    
    mutating func clear() {
        self.text = ""
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var object = Object()
    
    var body: some View {
        NewView(object: $object)
    }
}

struct NewView: View {
    @Binding var object: Object
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter some text", text: $object.text)
            .border(Color.black, width: 1)
        
        Button("Clear") {
            object.text = ""
        }
    }
}

Alternatively, use
 @Observable class Object {
     var text = ""
 }

